# Why tensorflow-gpu use both cpu and gpu in RTX 3080

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

My System spec.

```
os : window 10 pro
gpu : RTX 3080
nvidia_version : 461.92
cuda : 11.2.2
cudnn : 8.1.1 for cuda 11.2

tensorflow : 2.5.0-dev20210326 (also, I already try another version 2.5.0-dev, 2.6.0-dev20210328, 2.4.0, and 2.4.1)

keras : 2.4.3
python : 2.8.7
tensorflow.test.is_gpu_available()
2.4.0, 2.4.1 : False, but, change ./cuda/v11.2/bin/cusolver64_11.dll name to cusolver64_10.dll -> True
2.5.0-dev : True
2.6.0-dev : True
When is_gpu_available() True
```

I run the MNIST sample code on Pycharm and Jupyter notebook. And check task manager performance CPU, Memory(RAM), GPU Tap. CPU usage going up, Memory usage going up, GPU Memory usage going up, GPU Cuda usage going up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwNz8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZQBn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOw65.png)

**But MNIST sample code running by GPU is slower than only CPU use, more than 2x times.**

CPU runtime: 9.xx seconds
GPU runtime : 22.xx second

Why this symptom appears.

Comment: A big one like 3080 needs something challenging. Run the GAN model and see the beauty.

Comment: A GPU is a hardware surrogate of the CPU. You can not use the GPU without the CPU doing stuff to send it work. Sending this work takes a fixend amount of time. If your problem is computationally small, then its possible that sending the work to the GPU is longer than computing it, and therefore it can take more time in GPU than CPU.

Comment: @M.Innat Wow!! Amazing! In CPU GAN model sample code time for 1 epoch is 88.4 sec, but GPU time for 1 epoch is 4.5 sec. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @AnderBiguri Okay, I understand GPU surrogate CPU! Thank you!